# Find all positive integral values of n for which (2n + 1) is a factor of (n^4 + n^2). Justify your response.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integral values of n for which (2n+1) is a factor of (n^4 + n^2). Justify your response.

Comment: Well you can start noting that $n^4+n^2 = n^2(n^2 + 1))$.  You can justify this for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

$$m=\frac{n^4+n^2}{2n+1}=\frac{16n^4+16n^2}{16(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{16}\left(8n^3-4n^2+10n-5+\frac{5}{2n+1}\right)$$

So:

$$16m=8n^3-4n^2+10n-5+\frac{5}{2n+1}$$

Both sides are integers, so we must have $(2n+1)|5\implies n=0,2$.

We quickly verify that these give actual solutions, and hence we are done.

**Edit**: [this is conceptually the same as Bill's answer and remarks]

For a quick route through the polynomial division, write $16n^4=1+(2n)^4-(-1)^4$ and $16n^2=4(4n^2)=4+4((2n)^2-(-1)^2)$ and use your favourite division method for dealing with terms of the form $\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$.

Comment: Note that your  "Edit" is exactly what I did in my answer - see the note in my comment.

Comment: Ok. In any case it is worth explicitly pointing out the duplication so readers don't waste time grokking the same thing twice.

Comment: amended with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\,\ 2n\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2n\equiv -1}\ \,$ so $\,\ \color{#0a0}0\equiv 16(n^4\!+\!n^2)\equiv (\color{#c00}{2n})^4\!+4(\color{#c00}{2n})^2\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^4\!+ 4(\color{#c00}{-1})^2\equiv \color{#0a0}5$

Thus $\,2n\!+\!1\mid\color{#0a0}5\ $ so $\ n =\ \ldots$

Comment: **Note** $ $ We essentially applied that **Factor / Remainder  Theorem,** i.e.$\,2x\!+\!1\mid f(x)\iff f(-1/2) = 0,\,$ but did it directly using  modular arithmetic (after scaling by $\,2^d,\ d= \deg f\,$ to remove denominators).